# How to solve 'discord.http: We are being rate limited. Responded with 429.'

Tags: python, api, discord, bots

I created this discord bot, that I only use, which basically gets the voice chat of the author of the command, gets the activity being played in the voice channel, and change the name of the channel accordingly. I have no clue, why I'm getting this 429, Also it's my first time using discord.py so I may have used something wrong. Here is the code:

```
import asyncio
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

token = 'Token'
intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

async def my_task(ctx):
    voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    while True:
        if activities := [a.name for m in voice_channel.members for a in m.activities]:
            most_common_activity = max(set(activities), key=activities.count)
            
            await voice_channel.edit(name=f"{most_common_activity}")
        else:
            await voice_channel.edit(name="Other Games")
        await asyncio.sleep(15)

@bot.command()
async def set_channel_activity(ctx):
    bot.loop.create_task(my_task(ctx))


bot.run(token)
```

Answer (score -1):

You have been rate limited by discord. If you're using Replit, which I'm guessing you are, you could use `kill 1` in shell to refresh your ip.

Comment: Is it still happening?

Comment: Yes it is, and don't know what to do. Doesn't seem like this type of script should make that much request

Comment: Maybe the endpoint you are requesting from requires you to wait more than 15 seconds

Comment: Don't think so, and even if it did, I've tried making it wait more than 15 seconds, and it still timing out the bot

Comment: Are you running the program locally?

Comment: Sorry for late answer, and yes I am

Comment: Try performing the actions manually on discord yourself and see if you can

Comment: Also, are you running it as a selfbot?

Comment: What do you mean by selfbot? And also I tried it manually, and it let me do it